# Custom button javascript error on Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a custom button where I want to check for conformation. I wrote my javascript for conformation but I am getting error that

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:
>   Unexpected token ILLEGAL

What is the reason behind this error. Please help me to solve this error.

my code :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")}
var txt;
var r = confirm("Are you sure!");
if (r == true) {
    url 
}
```

Comment: What do url variable mean?

Comment: it is a url to my Vf page.

Comment: Hi Anu, did my solution work? if so, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code:

```
var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure!");
if (confirmation == true) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `url` in quotes. 
If you are evaluating your url using the `{!}` syntax, you need to quote that, eg
`var url = "{!salesforcefieldvalueOrCalc}";`
Try this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")}

var url = "{!salesforcefieldvalueOrCalc}";
var r = confirm("Are you sure!");
if (r == true) {
    //your URL should look like this line:
    //window.location.href = "https://na17.salesforce.com";
    //just make sure that url is evaluated as a string and you'll be able to
    //write it as:
    window.location.href = url;
}
```